# Handling AngularJS events in an interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

Is it possible to have an interceptor wait for some event before sending the request to the server?

Here is the code of the interceptor:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module("fuse").config(config);

  /** @ngInject */
  function config($httpProvider, $provide) {
    $provide.factory("httpInterceptor", function($q, $rootScope) {
      return {
        request: function(config) {
          // I need to wait for some event, read its argument and add this argument to the headers

          return config || $q.when(config); // Only return after handling the event
        },
        response: function(response) {
          console.log("Data Count: " + response.data.length);
          return response || $q.when(response);
        }
      };
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("httpInterceptor");
  }
})();
```

As you can see, before returning the config object, i want to handle some event that contains additional data that I need to add to the headers.
Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that,return your promise `var deferred = $q.defer();`, than when async method finish, you can resolve your updated config :

```
          'request': function(config) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            someAsyncService.doAsyncOperation().then(function() {
                // Asynchronous operation succeeded, modify config accordingly
                ...
                deferred.resolve(config);
            }, function() {
                // Asynchronous operation failed, modify config accordingly
                ...


               deferred.resolve(config);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

More you can read in [AngularJS Interceptors](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Matej, but sorry I don't quite fully understand. How can a service help me here?

Comment: You do not need service, you do not return config, but you return `promise`. And you wait for some event, when then event finish - then you can resolve updated config.

Comment: You return `promise`, but real return is in this code `deferred.resolve(config);`